# Grails redirect not working

Tags: ajax, grails, redirect

ismy controller does not work and I don't understand why here is it:

```
class FormmakerController {

def fileManipulatorService

def index = { }

def idProcessor = {
    String idToProcess = params.urlEncParam

    //Params lookalike urlEncParam:301-303-304-305
    if(idToProcess != null){
        String globalForm = ''
        idToProcess.split('-').each {item->
            globalForm += fileManipulatorService.fileProvider(item).getText()
        }

        //render(text: globalForm, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1")

        //response.sendError(200)
        redirect(controller: 'tools', action: 'index', params: [globalForm: String])
    }}}
```

Note : the controller is called from an ajax request and my redirect instruction need to call an action in a different controller with Text params.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, how is this called from the other controller?

Comment: @Colin The versioon I'm using is Grails 1.3.7

Comment: @Peter Ledbrook good question I just realize I was wrong: this action is directly called from an ajax GET request, I've edited my post

Comment: could the malfunction be related to the ajax request that generates the call?

Comment: I should have asked before: what do you mean it doesn't work? In what way?

Answer (score 0):

The params on your redirect looks incorrect.  Try:

```
redirect(controller: 'tools', action: 'index', params: [globalForm: globalForm])
```